# \themysection numbers in left margin (scrbook)

Tags: numbering, margins, sections-paragraphs, leftmargin

I would like to make chapter/section numbers appear in the left margin of a scrbook document.

While the following code is doing this for chapter/section numbers, it is not doing it for \themysection numbers, as I define a new command \mysection that numbers sections alphabetically.

Below you can find the MWE.

Does anyone know how to make the \mysection numbers appear in the left margin?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibtotoc, chapterprefix=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand*\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
    \ifnum\value{mysection}>0%
        \llap{\themysection\autodot\enskip}%
    \else%
        \llap{#3\autodot\enskip}%
    \fi%
}

\renewcommand*\chapterformat{\llap{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}}

\newcounter{mysection}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\themysection}{\thechapter.\Alph{mysection}}

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{
    \stepcounter{mysection}
    \section*{\themysection~#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\themysection~#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First chapter}    
        \section{First first section}        
            Text text text            
        \section{First second section}        
            Text text text
        \mysection{Appendix}        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\othersectionlevelsformat` is useless.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  bibliography=totoc,
  chapterprefix=false
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand*\chapterformat{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}}
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thesection\autodot\enskip}}

\newcounter{mysection}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\themysection}{\thechapter.\Alph{mysection}}

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mysection}%
  \section*{\makebox[0pt][r]{\themysection\enskip}#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\themysection}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}    

\section{First first section}        

Text text text            


\section{First second section}        

Text text text


\mysection{Appendix}        

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `bibintoc` option is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! this helps a lot. However, in the TOC, the entry for 1.A Appendix is not consistent with the entries for 1.1 and 1.2, as the word "Appendix" is slightly shifted to the left. Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: One could set \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\themysection~~~~#1} but this is not a clean solution...

Comment: @Christopher I fixed it with `\numberline`.

Comment: Thanks. I had to include \protect. The command for the TOC entry is \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\themysection}{#1}}

Comment: @Christopher Isn't it in the code I wrote?

Comment: True! I didn't notice that you edited the original answer